# ASP MVC2 model binding issue on POST with strongly-typed HTML helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

So I'm looking at moving from **MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.0 RTM**.  One of the conventions I'd like to start following is using the strongly-typed HTML helpers for generating controls like text boxes.

However, it looks like it won't be an easy jump.  I tried migrating my first form, replacing lines like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.Data.FirstName, new {maxlength = 30}) %>
```

...for lines like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Data.FirstName, new {maxlength = 30}) %>
```

Previously, this would map into its appropriate view model on a POST, using the following method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(AccountViewInfo viewInfo)
```

Instead, it currently gets an empty object back.  I believe the disconnect is in the fact that we pass the view model into a larger aggregate object that has some page metadata and other fun stuff along with it (hence `x.Data.FirstName` instead of `x.FirstName)`.

So my question is: what is the best way to use the strongly-typed helpers while still allowing the MVC framework to appropriately cast the form collection to my view-model as it does in the original line?  Is there any way to do it without changing the aggregate type we pass to the view?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** So the bind attribute worked well, but I didn't love how I had to apply it to essentially every posted view model.  I ended up changing the inheritance hierarchy such that all of our view models inherit from a base class that contains page content and other meta data, as opposed to being an aggregate property named `Data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Prefix = "data")] AccountViewInfo viewInfo);
```

This tells the binder that it should expect all values to start with *data*, so it will look for *data.FirstName*, etc.

Comment: +1 since that definitely will work.  Although I'm curious if there are any ways to enforce this more globally?  I'd rather not add the `[Bind]` attribute in every POST manually if I can avoid it.  It'd be awesome if I could enforce it in a base controller or some sort of class-level attribute that checked for non form-collection reference types.

Comment: Add the FirstName property to the Model itself, so you would bind with x => x.FirstName instead of x => x.Data.FirstName.

Comment: @mxmissile that would fix it, but the actual `Model` is a strongly typed container, where the strong type is applied to the `Data` attribute.  So from an architectural standpoint that wouldn't work for me in this case.

Comment: Marking as resolved since it's ended up being the fix we're going with for now.  If anyone has any ways to make this more generic, please add it.  Thanks!